# Css: How to implement tooltip in css correctly

Tags: css

The Code below shows tooltip at the right side using css when hovered as can been seen in the screenshot below

[image: Right Side Tooltip]

Please how do I make the tooltip to appear on the **top** of the name when hovered

```
<html><head>
</head>
<body>

<div data-tooltip="I am Nancy Moore">
<label>Name</label>
</div>
<style>
div:hover:before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: -3px 0 0 50px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

div:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    margin: 6px 0 0 3px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}


</style>
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you mean that ?

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

label:hover::before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    bottom: calc(100% + 10px);
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}

label:hover::after {
    content: '';
    top: -10px;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 5px solid #000;
    border-right: 5px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid transparent;
    transform: translate(-50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<label data-tooltip="I am Nancy Moore">Name</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the margin to 0 and z-index:1

```
margin: -3px 0 0 0;
```

```css
div:hover:before {
    content: attr(data-tooltip);
    position: absolute;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: -3px 0 0 0;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 3px;
    z-index:1
}

div:hover:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    margin: 6px 0 0 3px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-top: 5px solid transparent;
    border-right: 10px solid black;
    border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div data-tooltip="I am Nancy Moore">
 <label>Name</label>
</div>
```